# chrome extension image onload is not fired

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, onload

I'm trying to download an image from a google chrome extension. And for downloading here is my approach:

```
  const image = new Image();
  function loadImage() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, widthGraph, heightGraph);
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, widthGraph, heightGraph);

    canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
      saveAs(blob, 'D3 vis exported to PNG.png');
    });
  }
  image.addEventListener('load', loadImage, false);
  image.src = imgsrc;
```

But the `onload` is not even getting triggered.

If you want to look at the full code, they are available right here: https://github.com/maifeeulasad/React-Sight/blob/download-feature/extension/frontend/drawChart.js#L362-L378

My manifest looks something like this:

```
...
"background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content-script.js"]
  }],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab", 
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
...
```

**Can anyone help me debug what is the problem?**

Comment: Work for me in a quick test in devtools console so it may be a bug in Chrome or there's something wrong/weird in your svg data.

Comment: @wOxxOm you tried a toy-extension or this extension... this answer will be helpful, because... then I will look into other configurations...